# antialiasing on diagonal lines in Tikz

Tags: latex, tikz

I am wondering if there is any way to do anti-aliasing on diagonal lines like these?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red,thin](3.75,0.5)--(2,1.4);
\draw[red,thin](3.75,0.875)--(2,1.3275);
\draw[red,thin](3.75,1.25)--(2,1.25);
\draw[red,thin](3.75,1.625)--(2,1.1875);
\draw[red,thin](3.75,2)--(2,1.1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't that just something your PostScript or PDF viewer is supposed to do for you?

Comment: You make a very good point. Thank you.